# Batch Normalization in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I noticed there are batch normalization functions already in the api for tensorflow. One thing I don't understand though, is how to to change the procedure between training and test?

Batch normalization acts differently during test than during training. Specifically one uses a fixed mean and variance during training.

Is there some good example code somewhere? I saw some, but with scope variables it got confusing

Comment: Consider using the pre-defined layers from the high-level apis such as `tf.contrib.layers`.

Answer (score 9):

You are right, the `tf.nn.batch_normalization` provides just the basic functionality for implementing batch normalization. You have to add the extra logic to keep track of moving means and variances during training, and use the trained means and variances during inference. You can look at this [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/ops.py#L116) for a very general implementation, but a quick version that doesn't use `gamma` is here :

```
  beta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape), name='beta')
  moving_mean = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape), name='moving_mean',
                                 trainable=False)
  moving_variance = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape),
                                     name='moving_variance',
                                     trainable=False)
  control_inputs = []
  if is_training:
    mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(image, [0, 1, 2])
    update_moving_mean = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(
        moving_mean, mean, self.decay)
    update_moving_variance = moving_averages.assign_moving_average(
        moving_variance, variance, self.decay)
    control_inputs = [update_moving_mean, update_moving_variance]
  else:
    mean = moving_mean
    variance = moving_variance
  with tf.control_dependencies(control_inputs):
    return tf.nn.batch_normalization(
        image, mean=mean, variance=variance, offset=beta,
        scale=None, variance_epsilon=0.001)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One other quick question. Is a version with gamma really more complicated? seems you would just have to initialize another tf.Variable for it? The rest of the code should be the same, should it not?

Comment: Yes, you can follow the more general implementation in the link I provided to add `gamma`.